# Scanner throws Exception on nextDouble()

Tags: arrays, java.util.scanner

*This is the main class*

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            CC conto1 = new CC("alberto", 250.5);
            CC conto2 = new CC("francesco", 1240);
            CC conto3 = new CC("gianpeppino", 7834);
            
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            System.out.println(conto1.stampa());
            System.out.println(conto2.stampa());
            System.out.println(conto3.stampa());
            
            
            System.out.println("premere y se si vuole depositare, qualsiasi altro tasto se si vuole prelevare");
            String chose = in.nextLine();
            double importo;
            if(chose.equals("y")){
                importo=scan.nextDouble();
                conto1.onAdd(importo);
            }
            else{
                importo=scan.nextDouble();
                conto1.onSubtract(importo);
            }
            /*for(int i=0; i!=conto1.length(); i++){
                System.out.println(conto1.saldo());
            }*/
            System.out.println(conto1.getConto());
        }   
    }
```

**I get the exception below when typing a number like 405.3)**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. The exception occurs at any time but isn't present on compilation.

Comment: you are supposed to write in English , mio/a caro/a compatriota (FYI maybe is better to use a single Scanner, if you have the same source)

Answer (score 0):

Please write both your code and question in English.

The solution is simple: use a comma.
So write `405,3` instead of `405.5`.